# Easy Google Fonts not working for ul, li and a tags in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I have Google Fonts installed on my Wordpress site with the API key working and the font set. My font, Droid Sans works fine on h1, h2, h3 all set within the customizer but ul, li and a tags remain in the old font.

I have also tried adding these(a, lu, ul) in the Add CSS Selectors to no avail.

Any ideas how I can this working, or Google Fonts working in Wordpress in general?

Comment: The only reason it wouldn't work is if other styles on your site are overriding them. Use a browser inspector to determine which styles these are. Also...why do you need an API key for Google Fonts?

Comment: It is needed to feed the all the fonts from Google so you can select, whichever. "Easy Google Fonts" is set to override others, but doesn't appear to do on these tags.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding a new Font Control containing ul, li and a tags. Then editing these to Droid Sans in the Customizer under Theme Typography.